# Python Dataframe remove rows based on function return

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One of the columns in my dataframe includes a link. I have a function that will return true/false depending on if the link is valid (example- it doesnt return a 404 error). I have tried df.drop and df.apply and both of them created issues I couldn't fix. Here is the closest Ive gotten.

```py
df.drop((i for i in df['Column_Name'] if not check_link_valid(i)), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Currently, this is the error I get.

```py
KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
```

An alternative solution could be changing a value in one of the other columns of the row or adding a column with the value corresponding to the value returned from the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `axis=1` means you are trying to drop column names but `i` is not a column name. Did you read the `drop` documentation?